# Independent Unity event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have scene in unity where object - in my case its bottle - with some probablity should randomly apear by itsels.

For now i have this shit code:

```
public class randomBottleApearence : MonoBehaviour
```

{

```
public GameObject bottleOne;

   public int randomCounter() {
       
        System.Random ranGen = new System.Random();
        int ranNum = ranGen.Next(1,20);
        
        Debug.Log("Key is pressed. The number is " + ranNum);
        return ranNum; 
   }

    public void randomInvoke(){
        if (bottleOne.activeSelf == true || bottleOne.activeSelf == false)
        {
            if (randomCounter() == 4)
        {
            bottleOne.SetActive(true);

        }else {
            
            bottleOne.SetActive(false);
        }
        }
    }
       
void Start() 
{
    randomInvoke();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("f")){
        randomInvoke();
    }
```

}

}

So, i need to get rid of this clunky method to press "F" for invoke method and attach randomInvoke() to some event inside unity that invoke it without any manipulation from me until canceled.

Comment: Consider not having TypeNameNumber variables it will make people loose interest when you show them that you didn't care to name stuff yourself, which is unfair when perhaps You thought it wouldn't matter.  But it does to anybody having looked enough on code, so correct that instant code review fail to get more dedicated answers by providing meaningful variable names ... even if it ends up being BottleOne for instance.

Comment: Actually your comment is very welcome. I am new to sharing my code to people and to c# as well. So i learned something today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pressing "F" you can Invoke your function frequently with: [InvokeRepeating](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

Also: I don't understand the purpose of the if condition in the first line of randomInvoke(), the statement will always be true, so instead you can delete the line or change the condition.

Comment: I guess thats because i am still lerning and write shitty code. Thanks for the answer!